# How to keep receiving data while keeping data in state in order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, signalr

I'm working on this react table sorting when the user clicks on table header it needs to sort the table, sorting is working but the problem is I'm receiving new data every second through SignalR hub and it sets state `udata` to new data. When a user clicks on table header it sorts the table but again goes back to the new state changed by new data. And cancells the sorted table back to unsorted.

Is there any way I can keep sorted state and still receive data?

I'm new to react any help would be appreciated

```js
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      udata: [],
      sort: {
        column: null,
        direction: 'desc',
      },
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('/signalserver')
      .build()

    connection
      .start()
      .then(function() {})
      .catch(function(err) {
        return console.error(err.toString())
      })
    connection.on(
      'APIChannel',
      function(data) {
        this.setState({udata: data})
      }.bind(this),
    )

    async function start() {
      try {
        await connection.start()
        console.log('connected')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000)
      }
    }

    connection.onclose(async () => {
      await start()
    })
  }

  onSort(column) {
    return function(e) {
      let direction = this.state.sort.direction

      if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
        // Change the sort direction if the same column is sorted.
        direction = this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
      }

      // Sort ascending.
      const sortedData = this.state.udata.sort((a, b) => {
        if (column === 'appName') {
          // This sorts strings taking into consideration numbers in strings.
          // e.g., Account 1, Account 2, Account 10. Normal sorting would sort it Account 1, Account 10, Account 2.
          const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
            numeric: true,
            sensitivity: 'base',
          })

          return collator.compare(a.appName, b.appName)
        } else {
          return a.contractValue - b.contractValue
        }
      })

      // Reverse the order if direction is descending.
      if (direction === 'desc') {
        sortedData.reverse()
      }

      // Set the new state.
      this.setState({
        udata: sortedData,
        sort: {
          column,
          direction,
        },
      })
    }.bind(this) // Bind "this" again because the onSort function is returning another function.
  }

  renderItem(item, key) {
    const itemRows = [
      <tr onClick={clickCallback} key={'row-data-' + key}>
        <td>{item.appName}</td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">
            <i
              className={
                'fa fa-circle text-c-' +
                (item.appState === 'STARTED' ? 'green' : 'red') +
                ' f-10 m-r-15'
              }
            />
            {item.appState}
          </h6>
        </td>
        <td>{item.spaceName}</td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">{item.orgName}</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">
            {new Date(item.appUpdatedAt).toLocaleString()}
          </h6>
        </td>
      </tr>,
    ]

    return itemRows
  }

  render() {
    let allItemRows = []

    this.state.udata.forEach((item, key) => {
      const perItemRows = this.renderItem(item, key)
      allItemRows = allItemRows.concat(perItemRows)
    })

    return (
      <Aux>
        <Row>
          <Table hover responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="sortable" onClick={this.onSort('appName')}>
                  {' '}
                  Account Name
                </th>
                <th> State</th>
                <th> Space</th>
                <th> Organization</th>
                <th className="sortable" onClick={this.onSort('appUpdatedAt')}>
                  {' '}
                  Updated At
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> {allItemRows}</tbody>
          </Table>
        </Row>
      </Aux>
    )
  }
```

Comment: you need to save sort selection in state and while based on the sort type you need to sort data in render, instead of setting state "udata: sortedData", so this way when you state update from API then based on the sort you can directly render by sorting them

Comment: Added a solution, check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the sorting part of the function to new a function:

```
const sortData = (data, column, direction) => {
    // Sort ascending.
      const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (column === 'appName') {
          const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
            numeric: true,
            sensitivity: 'base',
          })

          return collator.compare(a.appName, b.appName)
        } else {
          return a.contractValue - b.contractValue
        }
      })

      // Reverse the order if direction is descending.
      if (direction === 'desc') {
        return sortedData.reverse()
      }
      return sortedData
}
```

You can use this function in `componentDidMount` before setting the state with the newData and also in `onSort` function.

```
onSort(column) {
    return function(e) {
      let direction = this.state.sort.direction

      if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
        // Change the sort direction if the same column is sorted.
        direction = this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
      }

      // Sort ascending.
      const sortedData = this.sortData(this.state.udata, column, direction)

      // Set the new state.
      this.setState({
        udata: sortedData,
        sort: {
          column,
          direction,
        },
      })
    }.bind(this) // Bind "this" again because the onSort function is returning another function.
  }
```

componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Code

   connection.on(
      'APIChannel',
      function(data) {
        let sortedData = []
        if (this.state.sort.column) {
         sortedData = this.sortData(data, this.state.sort.column, 
             this.state.sort.direction)
        } else {
         sortedData = data
        }

        this.setState({udata: sortedData})
      }.bind(this),
    )

   // Rest of the code
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Form, Card, Table, Tab, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import Aux from "../../hoc/_Aux";
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      udata: [],
      sysdata: [],
      expandedRows: [],
      user: "active",
      system: "",
      data: [],
      UserFilters: {
        appState: [],
        orgName: [],
        spaceName: []
      },
      SysFilters: {
        appState: []
      },
      intervalId: 0, //Scroll on top feature
      sort: {
        column: null,
        direction: "desc"
      }
    };
  }

  sortData = (data, column, direction) => {
    // Sort ascending.
    const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (column === 'appName') {
        const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
          numeric: true,
          sensitivity: 'base',
        })

        return collator.compare(a.appName, b.appName)
      } else {
        return a.contractValue - b.contractValue
      }
    })

    // Reverse the order if direction is descending.
    if (direction === 'desc') {
      return sortedData.reverse()
    }
    return sortedData
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("/signalserver")
      .build();

    connection
      .start()
      .then(function () { })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
      });

    connection.on(
      "SBUserBrodcasting",
      function (data) {
        let sortedData = [];
        if (this.state.sort.column) {
          sortedData = this.sortData(
            data,
            this.state.sort.column,
            this.state.sort.direction
          );
        } else {
          sortedData = data;
        }
        this.setState({ udata: sortedData });
      }.bind(this)
    );

    connection.on(
      "SBSystemBrodcasting",
      function (data) {
        this.setState({ sysdata: data });
      }.bind(this)
    );

    async function start() {
      try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("connected");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
      }
    }

    connection.onclose(async () => {
      await start();
    });
  }

    onSort(column) {
      return function (e) {
        let direction = this.state.sort.direction;

        if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
          // Change the sort direction if the same column is sorted.
          direction = this.state.sort.direction === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        }

        // Sort ascending.
        const sortedData = this.sortData(this.state.udata, column, direction);

        // Set the new state.
        this.setState({
          udata: sortedData,
          sort: {
            column,
            direction
          }
        });
      }.bind(this); // Bind "this" again because the onSort function is returning another function.
    }

  scrollStep() {
    if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
    window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - this.props.scrollStepInPx);
  }

  scrollToTop() {
    let intervalId = setInterval(
      this.scrollStep.bind(this),
      this.props.delayInMs
    );
    this.setState({ intervalId: intervalId });
  }

  FilterUserArray = (array, UserFilters) => {
    let getValue = value =>
      typeof value === "string" ? value.toUpperCase() : value;

    const filterKeys = Object.keys(UserFilters);
    return array.filter(item => {
      // validates all filter criteria
      return filterKeys.every(key => {
        // ignores an empty filter
        if (!UserFilters[key].length) return true;
        return UserFilters[key].find(
          filter => getValue(filter) === getValue(item[key])
        );
      });
    });
  };

  FilterSysArray = (array, SysFilters) => {
    let getValue = value =>
      typeof value === "string" ? value.toUpperCase() : value;

    const filterKeys = Object.keys(SysFilters);
    return array.filter(item => {
      // validates all filter criteria
      return filterKeys.every(key => {
        // ignores an empty filter
        if (!SysFilters[key].length) return true;
        return SysFilters[key].find(
          filter => getValue(filter) === getValue(item[key])
        );
      });
    });
  };

  HandleRowClick(rowId) {
    const currentExpandedRows = this.state.expandedRows;
    const isRowCurrentlyExpanded = currentExpandedRows.includes(rowId);
    const newExpandedRows = isRowCurrentlyExpanded
      ? currentExpandedRows.filter(id => id !== rowId)
      : currentExpandedRows.concat(rowId);
    this.setState({ expandedRows: newExpandedRows });
  }

  SpaceRenderFilterList(item, key) {
    const itemRows = [
      <li key={"li-data-" + key}>
        <Form.Check
          custom
          type="checkbox"
          value={item}
          id={"SBSpace-" + item}
          label={item}
          onChange={this.UserAppSpaceFilter.bind(this)}
        />
      </li>
    ];
    return itemRows;
  }

  OrgRenderFilterList(item, key) {
    const itemRows = [
      <li key={"li-data-" + key}>
        <Form.Check
          custom
          type="checkbox"
          value={item}
          id={"SBOrg-" + item}
          label={item}
          onChange={this.UserAppOrgFilter.bind(this)}
        />
      </li>
    ];
    return itemRows;
  }

  RenderItem(item, key) {
    const clickCallback = () => this.HandleRowClick(key);
    const itemRows = [
      <tr onClick={clickCallback} key={"row-data-" + key}>
        <td>{item.appName}</td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">
            <i
              className={
                "fa fa-circle text-c-" +
                (item.appState === "STARTED" ? "green" : "red") +
                " f-10 m-r-15"
              }
            />
            {item.appState}
          </h6>
        </td>
        <td>{item.spaceName}</td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">{item.orgName}</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6 className="text-muted">
            {new Date(item.appUpdatedAt).toLocaleString()}
          </h6>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ];

    if (this.state.expandedRows.includes(key)) {
      itemRows.push(
        <tr key={"row-expanded-" + key}>
          <td colSpan="6">
            <Card className="card-event">
              <Card.Body>
                <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col">
                    <h5 className="m-0">Upcoming Event</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto">
                    <label className="label theme-bg2 text-white f-14 f-w-400 float-right">
                      34%
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <h2 className="mt-2 f-w-300">
                  45<sub className="text-muted f-14">Competitors</sub>
                </h2>
                <h6 className="text-muted mt-3 mb-0">
                  You can participate in event{" "}
                </h6>
                <i className="fa fa-angellist text-c-purple f-50" />
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }

    return itemRows;
  }

  onClickfn = () => {
    this.setState({ user: "active", system: "inactive" });
  };

  onClickfnsys = () => {
    this.setState({ user: "inactive", system: "active" });
  };

  UserAppStateFilter(e) {
    let index;
    // current array of options
    const options = this.state.UserFilters.appState;
    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      options.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
      index = options.indexOf(e.target.value);
      options.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({
      UserFilters: { ...this.state.UserFilters, appState: options }
    });
  }

  UserAppSpaceFilter(e) {
    let index;
    // current array of options
    const options = this.state.UserFilters.spaceName;
    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      options.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
      index = options.indexOf(e.target.value);
      options.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({
      UserFilters: { ...this.state.UserFilters, spaceName: options }
    });
  }

  UserAppOrgFilter(e) {
    let index;
    // current array of options
    const options = this.state.UserFilters.orgName;
    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      options.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
      index = options.indexOf(e.target.value);
      options.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({
      UserFilters: { ...this.state.UserFilters, orgName: options }
    });
  }

  SysAppStateFilter(e) {
    let index;
    // current array of options
    const options = this.state.SysFilters.appState;
    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      options.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
      index = options.indexOf(e.target.value);
      options.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({
      SysFilters: { ...this.state.SysFilters, appState: options }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let Spacefilterlist = [];

    Array.from(new Set(this.state.udata.map(item => item.spaceName))).forEach(
      (item, key) => {
        const perItemRows = this.SpaceRenderFilterList(item, key);
        Spacefilterlist = Spacefilterlist.concat(perItemRows);
      }
    );

    let Orgfilterlist = [];

    Array.from(new Set(this.state.udata.map(item => item.orgName))).forEach(
      (item, key) => {
        const perItemRows = this.OrgRenderFilterList(item, key);
        Orgfilterlist = Orgfilterlist.concat(perItemRows);
      }
    );

    let allItemRows = [];

    this.FilterUserArray(this.state.udata, this.state.UserFilters).forEach(
      (item, key) => {
        const perItemRows = this.RenderItem(item, key);
        allItemRows = allItemRows.concat(perItemRows);
      }
    );

    let sysallItemRows = [];

    this.FilterSysArray(this.state.sysdata, this.state.SysFilters).forEach(
      (item, key) => {
        const perItemRows = this.RenderItem(item, key);
        sysallItemRows = sysallItemRows.concat(perItemRows);
      }
    );

    return (
      <Aux>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12}>
            <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey="user">
              <Row>
                <Col sm={2}>
                  <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
                    <Nav.Item>
                      <Nav.Link eventKey="user" onClick={this.onClickfn}>
                        User
                      </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                      <Nav.Link eventKey="system" onClick={this.onClickfnsys}>
                        System
                      </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav.Item>
                  </Nav>
                  <br />
                  <Card
                    style={{
                      display: this.state.user === "active" ? "" : "none"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Tab.Pane eventKey="user">
                      <Card.Header>
                        <Card.Title as="h5">Filters</Card.Title>
                      </Card.Header>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <h6>By State</h6>
                        <hr />
                        <ul className="list-inline m-b-0">
                          <Form.Group onReset={this.handleFormReset}>
                            <li>
                              <Form.Check
                                custom
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox1"
                                value="STARTED"
                                label="STARTED"
                                onChange={this.UserAppStateFilter.bind(this)}
                              />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <Form.Check
                                custom
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox2"
                                value="STOPPED"
                                label="STOPPED"
                                onChange={this.UserAppStateFilter.bind(this)}
                              />
                            </li>
                          </Form.Group>
                        </ul>
                        <h6>By Space</h6>
                        <hr />
                        <ul className="list-inline m-b-0">
                          <Form.Group>{Spacefilterlist}</Form.Group>
                        </ul>
                        <h6>By Organization</h6>
                        <hr />
                        <ul className="list-inline m-b-0">
                          <Form.Group>{Orgfilterlist}</Form.Group>
                        </ul>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Tab.Pane>
                  </Card>
                  <Card>
                    <Tab.Pane
                      eventKey="system"
                      style={{
                        display: this.state.system === "active" ? "" : "none"
                      }}
                    >
                      <Card.Header>
                        <Card.Title as="h5">Filters</Card.Title>
                      </Card.Header>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <h6>By State</h6>
                        <hr />
                        <ul className="list-inline m-b-0">
                          <Form.Group>
                            <li>
                              <Form.Check
                                custom
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="chec1"
                                value="STARTED"
                                label="STARTED"
                                onChange={this.SysAppStateFilter.bind(this)}
                              />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <Form.Check
                                custom
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="chec2"
                                value="STOPPED"
                                label="STOPPED"
                                onChange={this.SysAppStateFilter.bind(this)}
                              />
                            </li>
                          </Form.Group>
                        </ul>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Tab.Pane>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                  <Tab.Content>
                    <Tab.Pane eventKey="user">
                      <Table hover responsive>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th
                              className="sortable"
                              onClick={this.onSort("appName")}
                            >
                              Account Name
                            </th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Space</th>
                            <th>Organization</th>
                            <th
                              className="sortable"
                              onClick={this.onSort("appUpdatedAt")}
                            >
                              Updated At
                            </th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>{allItemRows}</tbody>
                      </Table>
                    </Tab.Pane>
                    <Tab.Pane eventKey="system">
                      <Table hover responsive>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>App Name</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Space</th>
                            <th>Organization</th>
                            <th>Updated At</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>{sysallItemRows}</tbody>
                      </Table>
                    </Tab.Pane>
                  </Tab.Content>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Tab.Container>
          </Col>
          <button
            id="myBtn"
            title="Back to top"
            className="scroll"
            onClick={() => {
              this.scrollToTop();
            }}
          >
            <span className="feather icon-chevron-up" />
          </button>
        </Row>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I don't have your whole code. It must be something with formatting. Or you can add it to codesandbox and I can test it for you. That is much easier

Comment: The code I added should work fine. Just take care of the other errors first and then add this code.

Comment: without your code it works just fine, the only errors I'm getting are `Line 52:   'sorterdData' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 68:   'sortData' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 105:  'sortData' is not defined     no-undef`

Comment: Add `this.` to the function where its called.

Comment: error on `'onSort' is not defined  no-undef` I removed `const` because it was giving error `onSort` is not a function

Comment: is there any reason you addded `sortData` function twice ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent component to perform the request and pass the unsorted values and sorting order value to a child component.
child component(table component most likely) will display data based on sorting order value.

Currently your component get mounted each time you change the state values

Answer (score 0):

Add a life cycle method called `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` or you can as well use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` to perform the sorting inside of this method, that way when new data is available it will automatically be sorted alongside with the original one that was there. hence all your other codes remain the same and the new data just takes it rightful place in the sorting.